# CodeIgniter HTAccess doesn't load CSS files

Tags: css, .htaccess, codeigniter

I just added a htaccess file to my codeigniter application that removes "index.php" from the url.  The URL's are working fine, but now the CSS links are not working, even though the references are absolute(i.e. "http://...")  The images as well as all other links work perfectly fine, but the CSS files won't load.  This is the HTAccess file.

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(main.php|images|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php/$1 [L]`

And yes my index file for now is main.php because i will be using two different applications on the same CI installation.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may also wish to try the following:

```
# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php/$1 [L]
```

This will allow you create whatever folders you want in the web root (styles, images, scripts) without having to declare them in the htaccess file.

Comment: do not forget the robots.txt and sitemaps.

Comment: That's irrelevant with this code, it will check if the file is valid in the filesystem and then redirect to the applications main.php file if these don't exist.  This will work happily for robots.txt, sitemaps - pretty much anything.

Comment: Sorry didn't watch out. Grate solution.

Comment: Calls to www.example.com will grab index.htm instead of index.php

Answer (score 3):

I use this. Is well commented, and obviously not written by me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

your htaccess file is missing one line :)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(main\.php|images|robots\.txt|styles)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main.php/$1 [L]
```

You can put your styles directory in the RewriteCond line. I added styles for example.

More info [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

Comment: In addition, you must add any url you wish to access through here. Otherwise they'll be redirected to the main.php/$url page (which then ofcourse, doesn't exist).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the *.htaccess* file I'm using now.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|design|img|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /a-cat/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The directory structure is like this:

[image]

The CSS file can be used in this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/main.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to this problem is: Use the .htaccess code from codeigniter as given below and on path of your css, js and images use the base_url function as shown

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase # The path to your project/official/hrm/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>the rest of path to yourfile">
```